# Применить каждую новую функцию к каждому новому элементу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modx

Есть код:

```
$(".gametime").append(moment.tz('16/3/0:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm'));

$(".gametime2").append(moment.tz('16/3/02:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm'));
```

Есть тег p с классом gametime

```
<p class="gametime1"></p>

<p class="gametime2"></p>
```

Как вы можете понять, я внедряю разные времена (код) в разные классы. Но не могу придумать, как можно автоматизировать этот процесс что ли... Чтобы на движке modx админ создавал класс и время, и время было точно применено к новосозданному диву

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
    function updateTime() {
     $(".gametime1").append(moment.tz('16/3/0:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm')); // Добавить контент в болк .gametime1 
     $(".gametime2").append(moment.tz('16/3/02:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm')); // Добавить контент в болк .gametime2 
    }
    setInterval(updateTime, 100); //Выполнять функцию раз в 100 милисекунд
```